# Selenium - Get name of all the products present on a ecommerce website page using Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

Suppose I searched on Amazon "Camera". Now a new page opens and I want to get all the product names present on that page.

I understand I need to use 'for' loop but I am not sure how to proceed. Please help me out.

I can get name of one product but how to get for all the products.
If I use for loop 
    for(i=0;i<"what should I put here";i++)
I don't want to put an integer directly but a size of list that has all the products. But I am not sure how to get the size.

Comment: I know that. But here I am not able to get the values of all the products in a list. 
If you could just try that and help me out, search any product on Amazon and get the names of all the products present on that page.

Comment: I voted you down because you haven't shown what you've tried. There are many options - you should at least try one first before asking us to give you the answer.

Comment: All I am doing is trying to learn these things as I have just started. I hope you don't mind me gaining a bit knowledge of automation. :)Just for your info, I did try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to gather all the elements together in a list. The id's for each result in the list (on amazon, I did the camera search in your example) are like result_1, result_2, result_3 etc. so you need to do a partial match on the xpath:

```
List<WebElement> resultsList = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath(".//*[starts-with(@id, 'result_')]"));
```

Once you have all the results elements in a list you can go through it with a for loop, something like:

```
        for (WebElement result:resultsList) {
            System.out.println(result.getText());               
        }
```

This should print out any text displayed for each of the items in the results list, probably you'll want to tailor the text to remove stuff your not interested in but hopefully this will give you a start.

Comment: This helped. Thank you so much.
But as you said it gives everything, so if I just want the name of each product then how would I get that?

Comment: I used this in the for loop:

System.out.println(result.findElement(By.tagName("h2")).getText());

is this right?

Comment: Yes,  that looks like it should do the job :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use **cssSelector** to list all the elements and use **for** loop to go through each element

> ```
> List <WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".a-size medium.s-inline.scx-truncate.s-access-title.a-text-normal"));
> for (WebElement e: elements)  
> {           
>       System.out.println(e.getAttribute("innerText"));    
> }
> ```