# InvalidSelector error when getting names of product with Selenium web driver

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get the names and price of a product on a e-Commerce page. I'm using Selenium and my code is:

```
        for element in WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.product-iWrap'))):
            product_name_tmall = element.find_element_by_css_selector('.productTitle a')
            product_price_tmall = element.find_element_by_css_selector('.productPrice em::text')
            tmallSpider.items['product_name_tmall'] = product_name_tmall
            tmallSpider.items['product_price_tmall'] = product_price_tmall
            yield tmallSpider.items
```

When I run it's giving me this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

I previously used scrapy with the same css selector and it yields the correct information:

```
product_info = response.css('.product-iWrap')
        for product in product_info:
            product_name_tmall = product.css('.productTitle a').xpath('normalize-space(.)').get()
            product_price_tmall = product.css('.productPrice em::text').extract()
            tmallSpider.items['product_name_tmall'] = product_name_tmall
            tmallSpider.items['product_price_tmall'] = product_price_tmall
            product_detail_link = 'http:' + product.css('a::attr(href)')[0].extract()
            yield scrapy.Request(product_detail_link, callback=self.start_scraping)
```

I'm not sure why the css path won't work in Selenium.
The HTML of the page is:

```
<div class="product-iWrap">
    <p class="productPrice">
        <em title="6599" data=spm-anchor-id="a220m.1000858.100725 ..." class>...</em>
    </p>
    <p class="productTitle">
        <a href="//detail.tmall..." target="blank" title="iPad Air 3"...>...</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

For this product, I want to get 6599 and iPad Air 3, and I want the information of all products on the first page. Any idea how to do it?
This is the URL of the page: https://list.tmall.com/search_product.htm?q=ipad

Comment: can you share the URL of page ?

Comment: if you awant to pick information about all products you need to use FindElements in selenium and store it

Comment: @JustinLambert https://list.tmall.com/search_product.htm?q=ipad

Comment: do you want search as "Ipad" and get all products ?

Comment: Just products on the first page. The search would be different inputs. But iPad is one of them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182821/selenium-get-name-of-all-the-products-present-on-a-ecommerce-website-page-usin this link will help you to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re trying to use an invalid CSS selector. The `::text` pseudoselector is not part of any actual CSS specification. It’s possible, even probable, that Scrapy supports selectors that are not part of the CSS standard. jQuery used to do the same, and the nonstandard selector support has caused no small amount of confusion for Selenium users, as Selenium adheres to *only* those parts of CSS that are supported by a browser’s native selector engine.

As a side note, if you’re using a CSS selector, and you’re not sure it’s correct, you can open the browser’s developer tools, and go to its JavaScript console. Type `document.querySelector("<put your selector here>")` and hit enter. If the statement returns an element, you should be able to use the selector in Selenium code. If it does not, you won’t be able to successfully use it.

In this specific case, I’d do something like the following:

```
for element in WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.product-iWrap'))):
    product_name_tmall = element.find_element_by_css_selector('.productTitle a')
    product_price_tmall = element.find_element_by_css_selector('.productPrice em')
    tmallSpider.items['product_name_tmall'] = product_name_tmall.get_attribute('title')
    tmallSpider.items['product_price_tmall'] = product_price_tmall.get_attribute('title')
    yield tmallSpider.items
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation @JimEvans